# How to create a pop up with Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, wijmo, knockout-3.0, wijgrid

I currently have a wijmo grid where a list of columns with checkbox appears after binding is done. I would like to add the checkboxes to a pop up so that it is visible only on click. The following code is what i have to hide and unhide the columns on checked and unchecked conditions.

```
 self.hideCols = function () {
            var columns = $('#Grid').wijgrid("option", "columns"),
                       listContainer = $("#columnsList"),
                       checkBox, isChecked;

            $.each(columns, function (index, col) {
                isChecked = (col.visible)
                    ? "checked = 'checked'"
                    : "";

                checkBox = $("<label><input type='checkbox' " + isChecked + " />" + col.headerText + "</label>");
                listContainer.append(checkBox);
                checkBox.click(function (e) {
                    columns[index].visible = $(this).children("input")[0].checked;
                    $('#Grid').wijgrid("doRefresh");
                })
```

Comment: You should consider using Knockout. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Just had to create a pop up using HTML and include the columnlist inside the 
`<div id="dialog" data-bind="wijdialog: {disabled: disabled, autoOpen: autoOpen, draggable: draggable, modal: modal, resizable: resizable }"
         title="Uncheck to Hide Columns">
        <table id="columnsList"></table>
    </div>`